# Issue using preventDefault() in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button i have in a middle of a form that i want to pull some info in by ajax. I have created a function and have the button setup like this:

```
<button id="class-list" onclick="updateMc()" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin: 0;">Update MC</button>
```

i have the function setup like this: But this still submits the form.

```
function updateMc(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var companyMc = $('#company_mc').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/saferscrapers",
                data: {
                    'company_mc': companyMc
                },
                complete: function(response) {
                    var responseText = response.responseText;
                    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(responseText);
                    for (var key in json){
                        if (json[key] != '') {

                            var element = document.getElementById(key);

                            if (element.type == 'checkbox') {
                                element.checked = (json[key] == "true");
                                element.value = (json[key] == "true" ? '1' : '0' );

                            }
                            else {
                                element.value = json[key];
                            }


                        }

                    }
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Pass the event argument into the function:

   ```
   <button id="class-list" onclick="updateMc(event)" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin: 0;">Update MC</button>
   <!-- Note --------------------------------^^^^^            -->
   ```

   That works cross-browser for modern browsers because even on browsers without a global `event`, there's an `event` in scope in the generated function the `onclick` creates.

   Beware, though, that it will **not** work for old IE (IE8 and earlier) or IE in "compatibility mode" where it breaks itself, because old IE didn't have a `preventDefault` method on the event object.

   Also note that using `onXyz` attributes requires that your functions be globals, and the global namespace is already plenty crowded.
2. Hook up the handler <s>correctly</s> dynamically using modern event handling techniques:

   ```
   <button id="class-list" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin: 0;">Update MC</button>
   ```

   then:

   ```
   $("#class-list").on("click", updateMc);
   ```

Given the issues with solution #1, I'd use solution #2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery functions to replace the onclick in the button tag.

case is to use dynamic content to recommend using this first, as if something stative use the second option.

```
$('body').on('click', '#class-list', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // code ...

});
```

OR

```
$('#class-list').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // code ...

});
```